# use jQuery to loop through array containing img urls and append to div

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, append

I am attempting to use jQuery to append a single image from a series of images to the bottom of a div, with the number of divs being theoretically infinite, so the images have to repeat.

To do this, I've tried creating an `array` with a list of the image URLs, and then appending a `img` to divs with class `.entry`, with the `src=""` of the image taken from the array.

My code: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3hpJf/5/)

```
function mascot_aside(){        
    $('.entry').each(function(i){
    var mascots = [
"http://i454.photobucket.com/albums/qq268/Princess_Kally/negi_chisame.gif",
"http://i454.photobucket.com/albums/qq268/Princess_Kally/negi_chachamaru.gif",
"http://i454.photobucket.com/albums/qq268/Princess_Kally/negi_eva.gif",
    ];

    $(this).append('<img src='mascots[i % mascots.length]' class="mascot" />'); 
    }); 
}

mascot_aside();
```

I've seen [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238245/how-to-fetch-image-icons-from-an-array-append-one-by-one-inside-divs), however, the problem with the answer code is if you have more divs than images, an "undefined" image loads.

Anyways, the images don't even seem to appear and I have no idea what I'm doing, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error from that code because you forgot to use the `+` concatenation operator?

Comment: I'm assuming that you know that the first place to check when your Javascript isn't working is the Javascript console. At least 75% of the time you'll see an error there that explains it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/79A3n/1/

Comment: I think this link will help you. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238245/how-to-fetch-image-icons-from-an-array-append-one-by-one-inside-divs?lq=1 )

Comment: I use notepad and Google Chrome and I'm only dabbling. Sorry. :x

Comment: @JPrakash Thank you, but I linked that one in my question and explained why it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Found some two errors in your code,

1. Declare array outside the iteration. (Not an issue but it should not be like this)
2. Having problem with value concatenation

Try,

```
function mascot_aside() {
    var mascots = [
        "http://i454.photobucket.com/albums/qq268/Princess_Kally/negi_chisame.gif",
        "http://i454.photobucket.com/albums/qq268/Princess_Kally/negi_chachamaru.gif",
        "http://i454.photobucket.com/albums/qq268/Princess_Kally/negi_eva.gif", ];

    $('.entry').each(function (i) {

        $(this).append('<img src=' + mascots[i % mascots.length] + ' class="mascot" />');
    });
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3hpJf/6/)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm very new at this, so I didn't even notice.